# Opening a file via Vim on GIT

Tags: vim

I'm following a tutorial on Uniswap forking (just to learn how this works) and I'm stuck a particular step.

How does one go from:

vim migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js

to

[image]

I'm only able to see:

[image]

How do I see the folders and directories ?

Comment: Note that using VIM is not related to using Git, except in that the default editor configured into many Git installations *is* `vim` itself. There is an entire stackexchange site just for vim questions [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user in that particular video is using the [NERDTree plugin](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree) for Vim.  Vim is very powerful and extensible, and it's possible to load a variety of extensions written in Vimscript to customize the interface, add editor features (such as LSP support), or various other functionality.

They're also using a custom colorscheme which is probably based on the Solarized palette.  You can also load a custom colorscheme with the `:colorscheme` ex command.

Answer (score 1):

There is another thing to notice, besides mentioned NerdTree plugin.

I think you are running your command from the wrong place.

```sh
vim migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js
```

This command tries to open the file set by relative path, or creates a new file, if that does not exist. As we see from your screenshots - the file exists in the tutorial, but it does not exist on your machine (the `[+]` mark after the filename on the second screenshot shows that).

My guess you need to `cd` to the right directory first (tutorial project root) and then only run your vim command to open the file.

As for your question about seeing the files and directories, you can do it without NerdTree plugin, using built-in netrw. Just type `:Ex` in vim normal mode.